# How to SetDirectory[] to the parent folder of the NotebookDirectory[]

Tags: pathfinding

How do I [`SetDirectory[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDirectory.html) to the parent folder of the [`NotebookDirectory[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookDirectory.html).

## Concrete example

[image]

pretend I am typing code into `notebook1.nb`, what do I type such that the output of [`Directory[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directory.html) is `path/to/parent_dir/`

+1 for elegant and easy to remember answer

Comment: `SetDirectory[FileNameDrop[NotebookDirectory[], -1] ]`

Comment: ``SetDirectory[ParentDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]]``.

Comment: `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
SetDirectory[ParentDirectory[]];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either

```
SetDirectory[ParentDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]];
```

or

```
SetDirectory[FileNameDrop[NotebookDirectory[]]];
```